# Internet traffic classification using Naive Bayes Classifier in MATLAB

Tags: machine-learning, pcap

I am doing a project in machine learning course on internet traffic classification. I have downloaded the trace file (in pcap format) from http://wand.net.nz/wits/. Now, I want to do supervised classification of the same data set and classify traffic as FTP, Mail, HTTP etc.

All this traffic classifcation I want to do in Matlab and use Naive Bayes classifier for the same. Now, I am stuck - how should I procees this pcap file in Matlab and obtain the class variables (like FTP, Mail, HTTP) in training phase.

Problems facing:

1. Unable to convert this pcap file into human readable format like CSV.
2. I open the pcap file in Wireshark and I am able to identify the traces, but how should I save it in a format so that Matlab can Process it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to pre-process the data into a format that your models can better handle.

I have used a Library for C# before called [Pcap.Net](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/).  This can allow you to read offline PCAP Files and then acquire and process the data you need for your Matlab models.

A tutorial for reading an offline PCAP File can be found [here](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Handling%20offline%20dump%20files).  From there, you can get the segments of the packets that you need and format them according to the model that you are designing.

Hope this helps!